# Calculating the power of something using while loop in java

Tags: java, loops, math, while-loop

I have been asked to calculate the result of x to the power of n using a while loop in java. This is my code:

```
public static double power(double x, int n){
    int i = 1;
    double y = 1.0;
    while(i<=n){                      
        i = i+1;
        y = y*x;                
        return y;
    }
    return y;
}
```

It is not working because it just returns the original x. I can't figure out what is wrong x_x

Comment: Your code doesn't work when `power <= 0`.

Comment: @JoriO I think the question means positive power but it's a very good point. I'll add this in. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You are returning y after the first multiplication, which causes the value 1*x to be returned.

Don't return y inside the loop. Only return it after the loop is done.

```
while(i<=n){                      
    i = i+1;
    y = y*x;                
    return y; // remove this line
}
return y;
```

Comment: Even after the fix, it would be better if fast exponentiation were used.